# How to print async data in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

this is my code and print is a page
and `getdata` is an async function that returns a promise

```
const print = () => {
  getdata.then((res)=>{
    return (<p>{res}</p>)
  })

  return(
    <>
      <div>{getdata()}</div>
    </>
  )
}
export default print;
```

how can I print data on the page?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
//Use a state to store fetched data
const [data, setData] = useState('');

//useEffect to fecth data on first render
useEffect(()=>{
  //Self calling async function
  (async()=>{
    let fetched = await getdata()
    let json = await fetched.json()
    setData(json)
  })()
},[])

return(
  <>
    <div>{data}</div>
  </>
)
```

And if data is an array of strings

```
//Use a state to store fetched data
const [data, setData] = useState('');

//useEffect to fecth data on first render
useEffect(()=>{
  //Self calling async function
  (async()=>{
    let fetched = await getdata()
    let json = await fetched.json()
    setData(json)
  })()
},[])

return(
  <>
    <div>{data.map(elem => <p>{elem}</p>}</div>
  </>
)
```

Comment: tnx how can i show {data} if data is an array?

Comment: Edited answer to suit your needs